# Sympy linsolve : EmptySet result

Tags: python, sympy

I am using sympy linsolve to find the solution of the systems of linear equations.

In #b, EmptySet is printed.

How do you find the solution of m?

```
import sympy
from sympy.solvers.solveset import linsolve

x,y,z,m = sympy.symbols('x,y,z,m')

# a)
m=1
ans1 = linsolve([x + y +z - 6, x-y+2*z - 5, x+3*y+(m*z) - 4], (x,y,z,m))
print(ans1)
# Out: {(10, -1, -3, 1)}

# b)
x=1;y=2;z=3
ans2 = linsolve([x + y +z - 6, x-y+2*z - 5, x+3*y+(m*z) -4], (x,y,z,m))
print(ans2)
# Out: EmptySet
```

Comment: Don't overwrite your symbol variables with values. Use a different variable name like `xval` and keep `x` just to refer to the symbol `x`.

Comment: Tip: if you don't understand the *output* of a function (such as linsolve) try printing out the *input* to make sure you understand what you are passing into the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have 3 equations in 4 unknowns, you will only be able to get a solution for 3 of them. If you want to see what value of `m` is in terms of 1 of the symbols, exclude that symbol from the non-linear solution of the equations:

```
>>> eqs = [x + y +z - 6, x-y+2*z - 5, x+3*y+(m*z) - 4]

>>> solve(eqs,exclude=[x])
[{m: 9/(2*x - 11), y: -(x - 7)/3, z: -(2*x - 11)/3}]

>>> solve(eqs,exclude=[y])
[{m: -3/(2*y - 1), x: 7 - 3*y, z: 2*y - 1}]

>>> solve(eqs, exclude=[z])
{m: -3/z, x: 11/2 - 3*z/2, y: z/2 + 1/2}
```